# Bind will not run at start up

Tags: unix, bind, init.d

I have the named script in init.d and a symbolic link in all of the rc#.d directories.  I can manually run the script and the symbolic links and named will start just fine.

I added "touch /test.test" at the top of the script and the file is not created on startup, so I am thinking the script is never run.  As far as I can tell there are no errors in any log anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: `chmod +x /path/to/your_script`? Otherwise, how about filling in some details like OS?

Comment: Which Unix?  It matters, for things like knobs to turn on.

Comment: I'm running the Amazon Linux AMI on EC2.

Comment: The script has execute permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hacky way to do it - call your startup script from `/etc/rc.local`, which gets executed last for every runlevel.

What does `/sbin/chkconfig --list named` report?

What does `grep id.*initdefault /etc/inittab` report?  That tells you the init level that the machine is going in to by default, and you can crosscheck that with what chkconfig reports, to verify that your script is turned on for your default runlevel.

Check the `/var/log/boot.log*` files to see if your named script is getting called or not.  Also examine /`/var/log/messages`.

If you are booting to say runlevel 5, you could try calling `sudo /sbin/init 3` from the command line to drop to level 3, hopefully you will see the list of shutdown/startup scripts that get run.  Runlevel 3 still have network access so you can do that without losing your connection.

Comment: After running `chkconfig --list named` I noticed that named was OFF for all run levels so I ran `chkconfig named on` and everything worked. Thanks a bunch!